# How to detect screen resoluion without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, screen, device-orientation

In case i want to check user's device by its resolution(i.e 300x600px for mobile, 800x600px for tab, and 1024x768px for pc).

but, how can i get the user's screen resolution when their javascript is disabled?

or is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: What do you want to do with the resolution information?

Comment: To give right page resolution for the user. like we cant get optimal for pc size resolution on mobile.

Comment: The resolution on my two-year-old phone is 1080 x 1920 pixels. Would you serve up the PC version of your page to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to apply CSS rules targeted at certain screen resolutions and orientations.

Answer (score 0):

@media should do it

By your specs:

```
@media (max-width: 799px) {
  @import url("/uri/to/mobile.css");
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  @import url("uri/to/tablet.css");
}
@media (min-width: 1024) {
  @import url("/uri/to/desktop.css");
}
```

Comment: but, how if i want to use it to load different page? like if i have made a page for each mobile, tablet and pc.

Comment: @user2265229 You can't load a different page depending on screen resolution if you're not using javascript. This can't be done in server side.

Comment: Revised answer* to make managing this problem a little easier. You'll need to use javascript to really get any farther than this. I'd suggest making your page as responsive as possible if you can't use javascript

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to create diffrent pages for eaxh reslolution juat use CSS media queries for adjust page according layout.

If you want diffrent page per resolution then you have to use some server side lib or function to detect browser resolution